Does anybody recognise what this tv show is? I thought it was The Outer Limits but maybe no?
So, at least 15 years ago I watched what I thought was an episode of The Outer Limits which was really good.  But as I've looked back through the synopsis of them I can't find it so I'm hoping that someone might know what I'm on about. The synopsis is as below from what I can remember.
A guy gets stranded or something near to a large house in the winter.  The owner lets him in and his whole family is there.  As the night goes on the women and men all start to behave unusual, the woman start pairing up with different men or the main man. Things always seem to change when the main guy wants things to change.  I can't remember how it all plays out but it turns out they are all cryogenically frozen and in a shared consciousness but the main guy has figured out how to manipulate the other minds.
I'm sure this is a wild goose chase but does anybody recognise what it might be?

I think it is Outer Limits. It's this episode: The Refuge

Thats the one.  I can sleep at night now :)
